# Search for a list of words in a paragraph

Tags: algorithm

I have a paragraph written in English. 
I have a list of words.
I want to check if the paragraph contains any one word
What is the best algorithm to do so:
Presently, I have the following but it seems very naive:

```java
private boolean findMatch(List<String> list, String param, ArrayList<String> skipChars) {
    boolean matchResult = false;

    for (String s : list) {
        if(skipChars == null || !skipChars.contains(s)){
            if (param.indexOf(s) != -1) {
                matchResult = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchResult;
}
```

}

Comment: your code returns true if only one of the words in the list is there?

Comment: yes true..is there an optimized way to do this

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad `For each word, I want to check whether the paragraph contains it.` but your program doesn't do it, it does `check if the paragraph contains any word in the list`

Comment: When you say words, do you mean strings or words.  For instances, are 'dog' and 'dogs' the same word or not in this problem. If you're looking simply for substrings, take a peak at Knuth-Morris-Pratt (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and maybe the grep source (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git) to see a nice, speedy implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. split the paragraph to wrods, and store them in a hash table
2. now for each word in your list search for it in the hash.

for real life applications this will probably do.

--EDIT--

if you cannot split the paragraph into words, and you need to tell if only one word is in the paragraph I suggest constructing a trie from your list of words, and then going over the paragraph and checking the trie for matches as you go.

Comment: splitting the paragraph into words is not that simple, as the paragraph might not be space delimited

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad if you have to treat the paragraph as a big string, there is perhaps no short-cuts. you have to check for each word in your list, if the big string contains it.

Answer (score 0):

In c# i usually use linq to entities for quering list and get result.

this is my code:

```
private bool findMatch(List<String> list, String param, List<String> skipChars)
    {

        if (skipChars == null)
            skipChars = new List<string>();

        var c = (from l in list.Except(skipChars)
                 where param.IndexOf(l) != -1
                 select l).Count();

        return c != 0;

    }
```